# how to do absolute pricing for custom options in simple product?

Tags: product, custom-options

i have added many simple products with custom options , but during select it add price to the default.

i donot want it to add price in default , actually it should replace it with the selected custom option price.

default $30

custom options :

first $50
second $70

on selecting first custom option, it should show final price as $50 instead of $80

Please suggest...

Answer (score 8):

Magento does not support this. The custom options prices are relative to the base price.
I think a better way of doing it, in order not to interfere with the magento pricing calculation system (that's kind of a monster) is to either set the prices for the custom options relative to the base price or set the base product price to 0.

Working with the same example you gave, 
you either set the prices of your custom options to `20$` and `40$`.
Or, if the custom option is mandatory set the base price to 0 instead of 30 and leave the custom options prices as they are.

Comment: ,it is right to set base price as 0

Comment: I don't know if it's a good approach to set the price to 0 business wise, but from the technical point of view it should work. You can set the price to 0 only if the custom options are required. In this case I think the minimum price will be calculated based on custom options also and you won't get 0 prices in the list.

Comment: @Marius do you happen to know why pricing for variations wouldn't update on the front-end when customer clicks on them?

Comment: For the record: I tried it and the product with base price 0 and required custom option is shown as price "0" in the frontend.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a couple of paid extensions for that:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-options-absolute-price.html
- https://www.magecomp.com/magento-custom-options-absolute-price.html
- http://www.absolutepricing.com/ (https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/absolute-pricing-for-custom-options.html)

I also have a pretty heavy patch for the core from a hired freelancer, which is bad, because it locks me to my current Magento version. I hope someone will replicate the functionality as a free extension someday 8(

It's a shame Magento doesn't have this feature.

Comment: I hope patch has been applied on Magento 2.3.2

Answer (score 1):

You set the product price to the lowest and add the custom options as absolute values or differential - up to you, it then calculates the difference if absolute. All very simple, look on the MagentoCommerce boards for absolute pricing, there are instructions how to do it.

We use special upload software (based on Heiler) to do all this (actually it keeps the pricing in supplier price and calculates at runtime but that is something else) - there is a drop in extension but it is only available to members of a special forum - there are also a few other extensions although we found them unreliable - so best you use the boards as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be:

> 1) Using this module:
>   https://github.com/magebuzz/Magebuzz_Customoption
>
> This module helps you set Default Value For Product Custom Option In
>   Magento. A blog about this module can be found [here](http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/2012/07/09/select-default-value-for-product-custom-option-in-magento).
>
> When you install the above mentioned module, you will see a 
>   `Product Options` menu in your Magento admin. You can set the default custom
>   option for each product from there.
>
> 2) After that, set the price of your product as 0 (zero).
>
> That's all.

Suppose,

- You set your product price as $0.
- You have three custom options with price $30, $50 & $80.
- You set the default chosen options for $50 (From `Product Options` menu in admin).

Then, custom option $50 will be automatically selected when you view the product page and your product price will be displayed as $50. When you select another custom option value, for e.g. $30 then $30 will be displayed as your product price.